# PyCharm throws permission error despite elevated to run as administrator

Tags: python, pycharm

I am looking for help to sort out the following issue in PyCharm:

Code below:

```
    #if there is a file with the same name, delete it first
    if os.path.exists(csv_name + ".csv"):
        os.remove(csv_name + ".csv")

    #Now save the df_csv to csv at the needed location
    df_csv.to_csv(csv_name + ".csv")
```

Error below:

> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:
>   'csv_out\example_csv.csv'

The file is created with correct name but 0 bytes.

PyCharm is already running as administrator.

Any clue would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `os.system('whoami')` show?

Comment: Thank you, still showing my personal id, but I've already set in the pycharm property to start it as Admin. Note I am using this in Windows,  I am not sure if whoami works in Windows the same way as in Linux?